# Deleting all identical files between two directories

Tags: linux, shell, diff

I am using the below command to delete all identical files between 2 directories.

```
diff -rs dir1/ dir2/ | egrep '^Files .+ and .+ are identical$' | sed -e 's/Files/rm -rf /g' -e 's/and //g' -e 's/ are identical//g' | source /dev/stdin
```

is there a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Following code works if the files do not have a space in it:

```
diff -rs folder1 folder2|grep "are identical$"|awk '{ print $2 " " $4 }'|xargs rm
```

In case you have too much files and you get an error on the rm (too much arguments):

```
 for i in $(diff -rs neustar neustar2|grep "are identical$"|awk '{ print $2 " " $4 }');do
    rm $i
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following command from the directory you want to delete files in it works quite nicely.

```
find /tmp/dir1 -name "*" -exec basename {} \; | xargs rm 2>/dev/null
```

the last argument is only necessary if you don't want to see error messages from files that aren't duplicated.  Also there is a small unintended consequence if by chance the name of the directory you are looking up file names in has the same name as a file in the directory that you are deleting files in.  While highly unlikely, you should be aware of that.